# C preprocessor parameter bracket covering the 'defined' keyword

Tags: c, preprocessor

```
    #if (defined AAAA)       //rather than-  #if defined (AAAA)
    #define BBB (0)
    #else
    #define BBB (1)
    #endif
```

In the first line above, the parameter bracket includes the "defined" keyword, is there a scenario where this can cause any problem? I know the usual way would be-

```
#if defined (AAAA)
```

Comment: FYI: [`defined (AAA)` is the same as `defined AAA`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of expressions involving `defined` is specified in section [6.10.1p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p1) of the C standard (link goes to N1570, which is the closest approximation to the official text of C2011 that is publicly available for free).  There are two forms:

> ```
>   defined identifier
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>   defined ( identifier )
> ```

with exactly the same meaning.  In other words, function-call parentheses around the argument of `defined` are *optional*.

In your hypothetical

```
#if (defined AAAA)
```

this is a use of the first form, with the optional argument parentheses omitted, and an extra set of *grouping* parentheses around the whole expression.  It's interpreted the same as if you had put an extra set of grouping parentheses around a regular `if` expression containing a unary operation:

```
if (! variable) /* ... */
```

is the same as

```
if ((! variable)) /* ... */
```

In most of the C codebases I've worked on, the preferred style was to use exclusively `defined identifier` without the parentheses.  I've never seen `(defined identifier)`.  It's possible that this used to be a more complicated construct, e.g.

```
#if (defined A && defined B) || defined C
```

where the parentheses are necessary, if only because nobody can remember which of `&&` and `||` has higher precedence.

Answer (score 3):

`defined` may be used as an ordinary operator inside `#if` directives.

C 2018 6.10.1 1 says:

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer constant expression except that: identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described below and it may contain unary operator expressions of the form
>
> `defined` *identifier*
>
> ```
>    or
> ```
>
> `defined` ( *identifier* )
>
> which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro name (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef` directive with the same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

Thus, there is no requirement that a `#if` directive using `defined` have `defined` as the sole or top-level operator. It may appear anywhere in an expression, including inside parentheses or even as:

```
#if defined x + defined y + defined z == 2
```

which would test whether exactly two of `x`, `y`, and `z` are defined.

Also note that parentheses are not required; using `defined (AAAA)` instead of `defined AAAA` just adds clutter.